# select only some rows when multiple columns duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select only one set of rows when I have 3 specific columns that duplicates. For example, in the table, I want only one of the 2 quotes to show as they are copies.

```
QuoteNumber|LineNumber|BillToCustomer|PurchaseOrder|CreationDate|Item
...........|..........|..............|.............|............|.........
11         | 1        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X1234 
11         | 2        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X5678
12         | 1        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X1234 
12         | 2        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X5678-2
```

So I have something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM vgQesHeader QH
left join vgQesDetail QD on QH.Link = QD.QuoteLink
```

And those criteria to put:

```
QD.LineNumber='1'  
COUNT(QH.BillToCustomer)>1 
COUNT(QH.PurchaseOrder)>1 
COUNT(QH.CreationDate)>1
```

And no clue how to do it.

I tried WHERE NOT but it doesn't seem to work.

***EDIT :*** 
This is my expected output:

```
QuoteNumber|LineNumber|BillToCustomer|PurchaseOrder|CreationDate|Item
...........|..........|..............|.............|............|.........
11         | 1        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X1234 
11         | 2        | John         | 35          | 2014-04-09 | X5678
```

Comment: Sound something basic and very simple, but to be sure please edit your question and add structure of tables (I didn't even understand how many tables you have there).

Comment: Some hints: use SELECT DISTINCT, use GROUP BY, remove columns which makes carthesian product

Comment: Please clarify your question - you put some relation, but we don't know is this expected output, or something else, and on what relation. I am not sure what do you mean by "One set of rows" or "columns that duplicates" or "only one of the 2 quotes".

Comment: I had my expected output. Does it clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *, row_number() over (partition by linenumber order by quotenumber) rn from tbl)
select quotenumber, linenumber, billtocustomer, purchaseorder, creationdate, item 
from cte
where rn = 1
```